# Filtering nodes in a network with checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, vis.js

I am trying to filter certain nodes in a network with checkboxes.
I've used the code below but can't get it to work. Any idea?
It's based on this [example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/dynamicFiltering.html) but instead of nodes selected from a list I want to use checkboxes for the nodes.

HTML (they use the duplicate names and id's for the checkboxes in the working example so that shouldn't be the problem)

```
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="nodeFilter" value="male" checked="">
              <span >male</span>
            </label>
        
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="nodeFilter" value="female" checked="">
              <span >female</span>
            </label>
            
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="nodeFilter" value="adult" checked="">
              <span >adult</span>
            </label>
    
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="nodeFilter" value="kid" checked="">
              <span >kid</span>
            </label>
```

Javacript

```
       /**
       * filter values are updated in the outer scope.
       * in order to apply filters to new values, DataView.refresh() should be called
       */

      /*
      filter function should return true or false
      based on whether item in DataView satisfies a given condition.
      */

       const nodeFilters = document.getElementsByName("nodeFilter");
       const nodeFilterValues = {
        male: true,
        female: true,
        adult: true,
        kid: true,
      };

      const nodesFilter = (node) => {
        return nodeFilterValues[node.gender];
      };
     
      const nodesView = new vis.DataView(nodes, { filter: nodesFilter });
      


     nodeFilter.forEach((filter) =>
        filter.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
          const { value, checked } = e.target;
          nodeFilterValues[value] = checked;
          nodesView.refresh();
        })
      );

      startNetwork({ nodes: nodesView, edges });
```

Here's the full code:

Btw When I run the code snippet it says nodeFilter.forEach isn't a function. Probably because nodeFilter is a HTML collection?
What's weird: in [the working example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/dynamicFiltering.html) also a HTML collection is used in that way for filtering the edges and it works!

```
const edgeFilters = document.getElementsByName("edgesFilter");
edgeFilters.forEach((filter) =>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <style>
    #mynetwork {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60vh;
      margin: auto;
      border: 0px solid lightgray;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      width: 50vw;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Dynamic filtering</h1>
  <div id=wrapper>


    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="male" checked="">
          <span >male</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="female" checked="">
          <span >female</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="adult" checked="">
          <span >adult</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="kid" checked="">
          <span >kid</span>
        </label>




  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="mynetwork">
    <div class="vis-network" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas width="600" style="position: relative; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;" height="400"></canvas></div>
  </div>






  <script type="text/javascript">
    function startNetwork(data) {
      const container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
      const options = {};
      new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    }

    /**
     * In this example we do not mutate nodes or edges source data.
     */
    const nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
        id: 1,
        label: "Eric Cartman",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: "Stan Marsh",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: "Wendy Testaburger",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        label: "Mr Mackey",
        age: "adult",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: "Sharon Marsh",
        age: "adult",
        gender: "female"
      },
    ]);

    const edges = new vis.DataSet([{
        from: 1,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 1,
        to: 3,

      },
      {
        from: 2,
        to: 3,

      },
      {
        from: 5,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 1,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 3,

      },
    ]);




    /**
     * filter values are updated in the outer scope.
     * in order to apply filters to new values, DataView.refresh() should be called
     */

    /*
    filter function should return true or false
    based on whether item in DataView satisfies a given condition.
    */
    const nodeFilters = document.getElementsByName("nodeFilter");

    const nodeFilterValues = {
      male: true,
      female: true,
      adult: true,
      kid: true,
    };

    const nodesFilter = (node) => {
      return nodeFilterValues[node.gender];
    };

    const nodesView = new vis.DataView(nodes, {
      filter: nodesFilter
    });



    nodeFilter.forEach((filter) =>
      filter.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        const {
          value,
          checked
        } = e.target;
        nodeFilterValues[value] = checked;
        nodesView.refresh();
      })
    );

    startNetwork({
      nodes: nodesView,
      edges
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `id="nodeFilter"` id's should be unique

Comment: Do not duplicate id's

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the working example they also use the same id's so that souldn't be the problem it seems. https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/dynamicFiltering.html
I think it has something to do with running through all checkboxes to redraw the network.
I edited this to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working,
I missed a simple thing:
`nodeFilter.forEach` should be `nodeFilters.forEach`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <style>
    #mynetwork {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60vh;
      margin: auto;
      border: 0px solid lightgray;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      width: 50vw;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Dynamic filtering</h1>
  <div id=wrapper>


    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="male" checked="">
          <span >male</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="female" checked="">
          <span >female</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="adult" checked="">
          <span >adult</span>
        </label>

    <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nodeFilter" name="nodeFilter" value="kid" checked="">
          <span >kid</span>
        </label>




  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="mynetwork">
    <div class="vis-network" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas width="600" style="position: relative; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 100%;" height="400"></canvas></div>
  </div>






  <script type="text/javascript">
    function startNetwork(data) {
      const container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
      const options = {};
      new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    }

    /**
     * In this example we do not mutate nodes or edges source data.
     */
    const nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
        id: 1,
        label: "Eric Cartman",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: "Stan Marsh",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: "Wendy Testaburger",
        age: "kid",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        label: "Mr Mackey",
        age: "adult",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: "Sharon Marsh",
        age: "adult",
        gender: "female"
      },
    ]);

    const edges = new vis.DataSet([{
        from: 1,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 1,
        to: 3,

      },
      {
        from: 2,
        to: 3,

      },
      {
        from: 5,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 1,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 2,

      },
      {
        from: 4,
        to: 3,

      },
    ]);




    /**
     * filter values are updated in the outer scope.
     * in order to apply filters to new values, DataView.refresh() should be called
     */

    /*
    filter function should return true or false
    based on whether item in DataView satisfies a given condition.
    */
    const nodeFilters = document.getElementsByName("nodeFilter");

    const nodeFilterValues = {
      male: true,
      female: true,
      adult: true,
      kid: true,
    };

    const nodesFilter = (node) => {
      return nodeFilterValues[node.gender];
    };

    const nodesView = new vis.DataView(nodes, {
      filter: nodesFilter
    });



    nodeFilters.forEach((filter) =>
      filter.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        const {
          value,
          checked
        } = e.target;
        nodeFilterValues[value] = checked;
        nodesView.refresh();
      })
    );

    startNetwork({
      nodes: nodesView,
      edges
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```